# Changing a background color of an item in Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview with a single item in it which is visible.

```
lv.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED));
```

This always returns a NullPointerException.

Also Im trying to understand why lv.getChildCount() returns -1 when there's a view in use.

Answer (score 0):

try listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, listView).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

[android - listview get item view by position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811536/android-listview-get-item-view-by-position)

Comment: could it be that this is only relevant for using Baseadapter?

Comment: What adapter are you using?

Comment: I use the builtin views provided by Android:
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);

Answer (score 0):

Try to change background color from your adapter. Here is an example about how to change.

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    **// change the background
    if(position == 0)
       rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);**

    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("iPhone")) {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be:

 **// change the background
        if(position == 0)
       rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
else
 rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);**

Handle both cases else it will give unexpected results after view reuse.