# Android - How to get reference to view in a custom layout?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-listview

I have a `ListView` that gets its layout for each item from "rowlayout".

I want to do something to one of the buttons in the rowlayout in my main activity, how do i get a reference to it `findviewbyid` doesn't work.

I guess i'm essentially not understanding a general concept of how to get a reference to a view in a custom layout- unless getting a view from a `ListView` is different. Can anyone help? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` is a `ViewGroup` so you can just iterate over its children:

```
int n = getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    doSomethingToView(getChildAt(i));
}
```

However, you must be careful. `ListView` is pretty special and only has a subset of children that you might expect. It only holds (roughly) references to children that are currently visible and reuses them as they disappear.

What you might consider is changing underlying adapter instead and than notifying the `ListView` that its adapter changed, so it needs to redraw children. Or alternatively, you can make the child of `ListView` directly listen for events that are supposed to change it and then adjust itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inflating a custom layout in the getView method of your adapter, you can get a view like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, parent, false);

TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.your_tv_id);
```

Comment: and the above code can be called from my main activity if my adapter class is a seperate one?

Comment: No, this goes in the getView method of the adapter. Edit: sorry, just reread your question, didnt realise you wanted to access it in the activity. Please disreguard

Answer (score 0):

You can use `partial refresh principle` if you implement `ListView` in the way of `ViewHolder`, just like this:

```
private void refreshPartially(int position){
    int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastVisiblePosition = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
    if(position>=firstVisiblePosition && position<=lastVisiblePosition){
        View view = listview.getChildAt(position - firstVisiblePosition);
        if(view.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder){
            ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            //holder.play.setBackgroundResource(resId);//Do something here.
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can use the answer from this [android - listview get item view by position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811536/android-listview-get-item-view-by-position) to get the child view at a position then call `findViewById()` on that child view.