# Android - setVisibility not working in ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a ListView which contains progressBars, I want to show and hide the progressBar inside a Thread, here is my code :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.ib_add_file) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FilePickerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
    }
}
```

When I pick a file it will be added to the ListView and start uploading :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PICK_FILE:
            if (data.hasExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_FILE_PATH)) {
                File file = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_FILE_PATH));
                Fichier fichier = new Fichier();
                fichier.setFile(file);
                ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Message>) chat_list.getAdapter();
                adapter.add(fichier);
                int pos = adapter.getCount() - 1;
                MessageHolder holder = (MessageHolder) getViewByPosition(pos, chat_list).getTag();
                Log.i("Fichier", holder.fichier.getText().toString());
                //the log is showing the right file name
                holder.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //the progressBar isn't showing !
                Log.i("ProgressBar", (holder.progress.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)? "Visible":"invisible");
                //the log is showing Visible !!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this function which i got from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811536/android-listview-get-item-view-by-position?answertab=active#tab-top) to get the added row from the ListView to handle the ProgressBar:

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;
    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MessageHolder msgHolder = null;
    Message msg = data.get(position);
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        msgHolder = new MessageHolder();
        msgHolder.fichier = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_fichier);
        msgHolder.iconFichier = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon_fichier);
        msgHolder.progress = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.pb_fichier);
        row.setTag(msgHolder);
        //msgHolder.handler = new ProgressBarHandler(msgHolder.progress);
    } else {
        msgHolder = (MessageHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Fichier fich = (Fichier) msg;
    msgHolder.fichier.setText(fich.getNomFichier());
    msgHolder.fichier.setPaintFlags(msgHolder.fichier.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    msgHolder.iconFichier.setImageResource(fichier.getIconFichier());
    return row;
}

private static class MessageHolder {
    ImageView iconFichier;
    TextView fichier;
    ProgressBar progress;
    ProgressBarHandler handler;
}
```

And this is my xml for the the rows of the listview :

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv_icon_fichier"
style="@style/AvatarImageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/descThumbnail"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_icon_fichier"
android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_fichier"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="22sp"
     android:text="Fichier" />

     <ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/pb_fichier"
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:max="100"
     android:minWidth="200dp"
     android:progress="0"
     android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why my ProgressBar is not showing ?

**Code Edited :** I realized that my problem wasn't relater to the Handler, I tried showing the ProgressBar directly from my onActivityResult methode but it's not showing !

Comment: try this `public ProgressBarHandler(ProgressBar progressBar) {super(Looper.getMainLooper());
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }`  see if it helps

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have edited my code, my problem isn't related to the Handler, have a look on my new onActivityResult code.

Comment: have you tried setting the progress ? like: holder.progress.setProgress(50);

Comment: it's not working too ...

Comment: yes it will not work i just forget, i never paid attention to the other post. i will try to  post an answer okay sir

Answer (score 1):

This is `ListView`'s parent's

```
↳   android.view.ViewGroup
       ↳    android.widget.AdapterView<android.widget.ListAdapter>
           ↳    android.widget.AbsListView
```

looking at that i might even say i will call `mylistView.removeViewAt(3);` and that should work because of `ViewGroup` but it doesn't because of `AdapterView`..
Why i am saying this is that, i am no genius, that post has 44 upvotes, which means its legit, but i do not think that will be the way to go if you want to single out Update a `View` backed by an `AdapterView` because the `getView` method will override it your changes,even though the changes occur it doesn't neccessarily occur on your preffered `View` the `View` at position 0 is what the rest of the `View` start drawing from. eg, if you have an initial `View` with a visible `TextView` and an invisible `EditText` then all the `View`s will be like that unless you change one `View` before the `getView` returns(*i have not used that method/way before and i am speaking with backed assumptions*), so instead put another variable in your datasource like `boolean needsupdate` and check for `needsupdate` in your `getView` and change the `Visibilty` there. that will be the legit way to my intelligence -(maybe i might be a little off here). but give it a try

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I really have problem in understanding what you mean, where exactly should i add the needsupdate variable and how I'm supposed to use it ?

Comment: in your dataObject, like you have a class that is your data object like this public class source{boolean needsupdate; String name;} etc etc , do you get me? in your case it should be `Fichier` then you check for it like `if(Fichier.needsupdate) // now change the visibility` @user3578325

Comment: hw was it sir @user3578325

Comment: it worked but there still some bugs so I changed the progressBar with a simple text view which shows the percentage and it works fine, thanks any way :)

Comment: aww you should have let me know about it maybe i could have extended my help, but im glad you found a way. btw if you weren't the one who upvoted, well you can give me an upvote :) lol,  if you were its ok @user3578325

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the file retrieval code into a worker thread like this?

```
// set progressBar .VISIBLE first 

// then...    
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                // file retrieval code

            }
        }).start();
```

Here is [how it solved my own problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40767263/1827488) & here are [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads).