# Is it possible to color only specific items in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a question. I have an array of objects which I've added into an ArrayAdapter and the adapter in a listview. My listView is coloured in a color on odd positions and on even in another color.
Now comes the tricky part. 
My object is composed of Strings id and name, String comments and a date.
Can I colour the entries that have the id/name preset?
For example, If i login and I want to see the listview, the entries where I appear (I already preserved the id with shared preferences) are coloured in another color than the other. From 5 entries, lets say, I appear in 3 of them, at random position. How to color the positions where I appear?

Thank you!

Comment: override `getView`

Comment: check if this solution helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853691/coloring-specific-item-is-listview

Comment: You need to build a custom adapter. You could specify view changes in the adapter by according to list item data at each position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something very similar. I wanted to change the font color instead of the whole item but you can replace my code with yours.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View mView = v ;
    if(mView == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if(items.get(position) != null ) //here you can match IDs and change the accordingly 
    {
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setText(items.get(position));
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
        int color = Color.argb( 200, 255, 64, 64 );
            text.setBackgroundColor( color );

    }

    return mView;
}
```