# ListView returns null when calling getChildAt method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do a to-do list where when I add a new element on the listView the file where the data is stored automatically saves the changes.

The problem appears when I call the method listView.getChildAt(i) because it returns null.

The function is called after adding a new element on the list and after calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method.

```
public void save(){
        int i = 0;
        View row= null;
        CheckBox x;
        File archive = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"file.txt");
        //list has been declared before
        try{
            PrintWriter fOUT = new PrintWriter(archive);
            for(String article : list){

                row = (View) listView.getChildAt(i);
                x = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.check);

                if(x.isChecked())
                {
                    fOUT.println(article+";1");
                }
                else
                {
                    fOUT.println(article+";0");
                }
                i++;
            }
            fOUT.close();
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,new String[]{archive.getPath()},null,null);
        }
        catch(IOException ignored){
        }
    }
```

Here there is the XML layout of the ListItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/check"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:textColor="@color/bianco"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bottone"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="rimuovi"
        android:background="@drawable/my_icon_delete" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bottone"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="formattazioneTesto"
        android:checked="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `ListView returns null when calling getChildAt method` ? Who returns null?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207347/7434090

Comment: If you have 100 articles in your list then the listview maybe displays 10. For the rest you have to scroll. And your listview will only have about ten children. So you cannot use all values of i.

Comment: The solution of @GavinWright solved my problem. thanks!