# How can I get Listview child position, if child is clicked?

Tags: android, listview

My app has `ListView` with children `TextView` and `Button`. (Refer to image)

[image]

How can i get position of button if it is clicked ?

**Adapter**

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public HistoryAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context,c, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.historylist, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    text.setText(body);
}

}
```

**ListView onClick event**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setCancelable(false);
    getDialog().setTitle("History");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history,null);
    back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    c = resolver.query(Contract.SaveRunning.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    adapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(), c, 0);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            setChart(position);
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return view ;
}
```

Comment: what you want exactly, do you want to set different action on differrent child click

Comment: yes, each view has different action

Comment: Hello @Error have you tried `list.getItemAtPosition(position);` to get the current position (Clicked) and if you want it as String you can add .toString(). let me know if it worked :P

Comment: hi @Skizo i handled this issue from Adapter class to each view it works now... i do not understand your methode , how use list.getItemAtPosition(position) return certain view  ?

Comment: I thought you wanted to get the position... to get the view you can do list.getChildAt(position); to get the view

Comment: Also you con check this[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24864536/4385913) to get the view

Comment: @Skizo this answer looks useful .. i also can get each view and set itemClickListener from adapter Class .. thanks Skizo for help :)

Comment: @Error Oh, okay, but I'm asking to you because your answer must be marked as a correct... so you should mark any question as a correct, do you want me to put my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the view you can do it as follows :

```
list.getChildAt(position);  //To get the view
```

Also you could do like [this guy does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24864536/4385913):

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
    return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
} else {
    final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
    return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
}
```

This also would work.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use something like this inside your **onClick** method to display item postion:

```
String value = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Where **lv** is ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but a good solution to this question is:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ixChild = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild( id );
        ixGroup = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup( id );
        setChart(position);
        dismiss();
    }
```

In this way, ixGroup contains the index of the clicked group and the ixChild contains the index of the child within the group.