# Change CheckedTextView text color if the item is checked

Tags: android

I need to change the textcolor of CheckedTextView if the CheckedTextView is checked on a ListView. Is there a way to do this? This is my code below:

```
public class Surv_list extends Fragment {
    public View row;

    final String[] OPSys = new String[]{"q", "w","e", "r"
    };
    ListView myList;
    Button getChoice, clearAll;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyUserChoice" ;
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlay, container, false);
View view=inflater.inflate( android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, container, false);
        myList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        clearAll = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.clearall);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.task_item, OPSys);
        myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES)){

            LoadSelections();
        }
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                SaveSelections();

            }

        });


        clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ClearSelections();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    private void SaveSelections() {
// save the selections in the shared preference in private mode for the user

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String savedItems = getSavedItems();
        prefEditor.putString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), savedItems);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }

    private String getSavedItems() {
        String savedItems = "";
        int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (this.myList.isItemChecked(i)) {
                if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                    savedItems += "," + this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);

                } else {
                    savedItems += this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return savedItems;
    }

    private void LoadSelections() {
// if the selections were previously saved load them

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES.toString())) {

            String savedItems = sharedpreferences.getString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), "");
            selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));

            int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String currentItem = (String) myList.getAdapter()
                        .getItem(i);
                if (selectedItems.contains(currentItem)) {
                    myList.setItemChecked(i, true);


                } else {
                    myList.setItemChecked(i, false);

                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void ClearSelections() {
// user has clicked clear button so uncheck all the items
        int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            this.myList.setItemChecked(i, false);
        }
// also clear the saved selections
        SaveSelections();
    }

}
```

And this is the CheckedTextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"

    />
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: if checkbox.isChecked() textView.setTextColor() whats the problem with that?

Comment: See following post probably help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811536/android-listview-get-item-view-by-position

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/b" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

```xml
<CheckedTextView
    ...
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_my_checked"
    ... />
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).