# How to check listview row Edittexts are empty or not when click submit button?

Tags: android, listview, button, android-edittext

I have `ListView`, populating rows using adapter class. In row i have `EditText`. Now when i click submit button in activity, i need to check all rows edit texts for empty. If any `EditText` is empty i want to display toast message. How to achieve this. small code snippet need.

Comment: Please share your small code snippet of what you have tried. We can help you in adding code to that.

Comment: Just check the edittext data lenght of corresponding position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way is
 - You store the data in the `EditText` whenever user input data into an `Object` or `List`
 - Then when Submit `Button` is clicked, just need to check the `Object` is null or not

**Or**

You can find each item (row) in `ListView` by position

```
 public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    }
```

Then find the `EditText` in each row

```
EditText editText  = getViewByPosition(pos,listView).findViewById(R.id.editext_id);
```

Finally check it empty or not

```
if(editText.getText().length == 0){
        // EditText is empty, display toast here
        Toast.makeText("","");
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: nice answer...thank you gor ur help

Comment: glad to hear that :D

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
sUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (sUsername.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

This is an example. Of course, you need to get this EditText from your row first.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the items of the listview, get the **TextView** by id from the listview item and check the length of its text

You can get the listview item like the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24864536/1534554)

```
for(int i = 0; i<listview.getCount(); i++){
        TextView tv = ((View)listview.getViewByPosition(i, listview)).findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if(tv.getText().toString().length() == 0){
            tv.setError("This is required");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you for what you want it will check the empty cell of list:

```
  private int checkForEditText() {
    for (int i = 0; i < yourListSize; i++) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(youlistSize.get(i))) {
            //return positin of empty cell
            return i;
        }
    }
   //if no cell is empty it retur -1
    return -1;

}
```

Comment: this is also good...thank u boss...