# android get checkbox from right row in list view

Tags: android, checkbox

in my android app i have a custom list view.
in each row is an checkbox.

i would like to check / uncheck the checkbox with each touch on the same row and / or with an touch on a checkbox.

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

SelectCheckBox = (CheckBox) ListView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.SelectCheckBox);

SelectCheckBox.toggle();
            }
});
```

if i touch row 3, the checkbox in row 3 will be checked / unchcheck.

but how can i realize this, with an touch directly on the checkbox.
i would like to give a toast feedback with "You checked Checkbox X"
(X = row-number of Checkbox)

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24864536/1320616

Comment: In your adapter, and an `onCheckedListener` to the `CheckBox` there.

Comment: but how can i find the checkbox by id and set an oncheckedlistener on this, if i haven't the child position of the list view before

Comment: it depends on how you feed your list, but a trick that you could use is:
in each row add a textview containing your ID or whatever you want to show in your toast. Set visibility to GONE so your list will look the same. Hence, you can retrieve the "hidden" ID when the user clicks any row

Comment: sry, but i don't understand how i can solve this problem. i know, that i have to set an general onchecklistener for my checkboxes. this check listener have to listen dynamic for this checkbox, which i have checked (for example: i checked the box in row 3. but how i can find this than via ID?

Comment: okay i found the solution. i put this onchangelistener in my adapter - how Eric told this before. thx !