# How to get a reference to a ViewHolder, from inside another ViewHolder? (RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with some `view`'s/`card`'s (let's call it a view for now), which all contain the same things, including a `View` that I'm using as a divider bar.

I want to be able to change the properties of this divider bar in the `view` above the current one. So say I click on the card that says `test3`, I want to be able to set the properties of the divider bar that's in the `test2` `view`.

#### To clarify:

I only need a reference to the `ViewHolder` for the view **above** (or any other for that matter) the one I click, that's all. How should I do this?

[image]

```
public class StuffManagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StuffManagerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<StuffManagerClass> stuffList;
    private Context context;
    private String TAG = "CStA";
    DBHandler dbHandler;
    ArrayList<String> tagArray = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public StuffManagerAdapter(List<StuffManagerClass> stuffList, Context context) {
        this.stuffList = stuffList;
        this.context = context;
        dbHandler = DBHandler.getInstance(context);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView DeviceTV, NameTV, TagTV;
        private ImageButton editButton, deleteButton;
        public ImageView tagWarningImage;
        View view, bottomBar ,cover;

        public MyViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);
            this.view = view;
            DeviceTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SMVFDeviceTextView);
            // etc., etc.

            editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do stuff
                }
            });
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do stuff
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_stuffmanagervariablefragment, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final StuffManagerClass sc = stuffList.get(position);

        // Initialize card, set all textviews
        holder.DeviceTV.setText(sc.getDevice());
        holder.NameTV.setText(sc.getName());
        holder.TagTV.setText(sc.getTag());
        sc.setPosition(position);

        
        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                // This is where I would like to get a reference to the divider bar on the other view/card
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stuffList.size();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- TextViews and stuff -->

        <View
            android:id="@+id/SMVFDividerBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LL2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You can get the object of view by position and make changes to the view accordingly.. check this link to know how to get the Item's view by position - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811536/android-listview-get-item-view-by-position

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't know why I didn't realize this sooner, but it works.

First, create an instance variable (please correct me if this is not an instance variable).

```
public class StuffManagerAdapter extends 
                    RecyclerView.Adapter<StuffManagerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
```

Then, assign this variable in the `onCreateViewHolder()`method like this:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.thingy, parent, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) parent;
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Then, in your `onBindViewHolder()` method, you can access the other `ViewHolder`'s like this:

```
mRecyclerView.getChildAt(holder.getAdapterPosition-1);
```

You can set this to a variable, or call stuff like `findViewById()` on it directly.

Obviously, you can manually input any position you want in the `getChildAt()` statement, and you can find any object in the view by using `findViewById()`.

Comment: Also this is helpful: 
mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

Comment: Wouldn't a better way to do this be to override the `onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)` method and inside that method set `mRecyclerView = recyclerView` ?

Answer (score 0):

it would have been easy if you would have posted your adapter code too,

well when you click on some item it gives you its position and you can handle other items too by mItems.getAdapterPosition() +1 or -1

here is simple example

In your `onClickListerner` in `ViewHolder` all you need to do is

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Do something with item at mItems.getAdapterPosition() -1

    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're calling `getAdaterPostin()` on.. I've tried calling it on pretty much everything in my code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you call it inside your `recyclerview` and it does work, I have always used it, post your adapter code then I can help you

Comment: @Timmiej93 Does your `onClick works? I mean have u tested it by showing simple toast?

Comment: Yes, everything works just fine. I got an `onLongClick` and `onTouch` listener on the view as well in my code, all working fine.

Comment: then try displaying position of item by `stuffList.getAdapterPosition()` in toast, it should give u the current position

Comment: It's not the position that I'm having issues with, I'm having trouble with getting an actual reference to the little blue divider bar that you can see, so I can set a visibility parameter on it.

Comment: bro, if you get the actual position of the view then we can handle the views  with respect to that position by `-1`, `+1`, feel me?

Comment: I **can** get the position of the view that I'm clicking (`onBindViewHolder` has a position variable), and I understand that `that view - 1` equals the view above the current one, but how do I get a reference to the `View` with id `SMVFDividerBar` then?