# How to get the actual index of a child in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I am currently using the `getChildAt` method for getting the child rows inside a `ListView`. The problem with this is that it only gets the child correctly if the `ListView` is scrolled all the way to the top.

If I were to scroll down a bit so that the first row is hidden and call the `getChildAt` method for position 1 it would get the view that is third in the `ListView`.

Is there a way to get the child view with an actual position rather than the position visible on the screen? So  that in the case above the `getChildAt` would still return a view (2nd child) even if it isn't visible on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
    return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
} else {
    final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
    return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
}}
```

reference: [android - listview get item view by position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811536/android-listview-get-item-view-by-position)