# How to get the checkbox of my first item in a ListView?

Tags: android, firebaseui

I am trying to get the Checkbox of the first item in a ListView. My code below:

```
Query recent = databaseRef.limitToLast(5);
FirebaseListAdapter<Item> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Item>(
        this, Item.class, R.layout.custom_list_item, recent

) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, Item item, int i) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item)).setText(item.getName());
        ((NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker)).setValue(item.getQuantity());
        ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setChecked(false);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.prosfora)).setText("s" +
                "e prosfora");

         View firstItem = itemLst.getChildAt(0);


    }


};

itemLst.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I get the first item from the ListView but I don't know how I can get the checkbox from that first item.

Comment: Did you mean first visible item?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811536/android-listview-get-item-view-by-position does this help?

Comment: What's wrong with `(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox))` you already have a few lines above?

Answer (score 0):

ok. i figured it out myself. i replaced

```
((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setChecked(false);
```

with

```
CheckBox checkBox_i = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
checkBox_i.setChecked(false);
```

then i put a setOnCheckedChangeListener in checkBox_i and i did my "TODO"
   (actually i wanted all checkboxes not only the first)