# How to get ID of Button that was generated from SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter

I used SQLiteAssetHelper. I connected SQLite database to connect to my populate_list.xml. Buttons gets sub_products column from my table. I am trying to get the ID of button. When I used ViewFindById(name_of_button). It returns null. I am thinking maybe I need refresh but I don't exactly know how to do that.

This is my CoreOpenDB.class. This is not Mainactivity

```
public class CoreOpenDB  extends ListActivity {

private Cursor products;
private MyDatabase db;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = "test"; // or other values
    if(b != null)
        value = b.getString("key");


    db = new MyDatabase(this);
    products = db.getProducts(value); 

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.populate_list,
           products,
            new String[] {"sub_products"},
            new int[] {R.id.text_list});

    getListView().setAdapter(adapter)
}
```

This is populate_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/text_list"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="Sample Product"
android:padding="25px"
android:textColor="#333"
android:textSize="38dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the result
[image]

I need to get id's of each item. Thank you .

Comment: You can get the row view from the adapted.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to have buttons rather than TextView ?

Comment: I need the buttons to make actions if they are clicked. That will transfer to another sub category of each item until it goes to the single item that shows its details. @cricket_007

Comment: I'll try the row view from the adapter. btw, im searching ListAdapter documentation

Comment: instead of `<Button>` just use `<TextView>` (or simply use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as your layout) and setup `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` and use the last parameter passed to the `onItemClick` method

Comment: @pskink . do you mean I code getListView().onItemClickListener ? Sorry I'm new to this. I don't exactly understand the setup part

Comment: getListView().setOnItemClickListener(...)

Comment: OK. i'll be back in a bit.

Comment: I'm sorry. What parameter is needed for getListView().setOnItemClickListener()?

Comment: and what do `AdapterView#setOnItemClickListener` docs say?

Comment: ok i'll read it. ur a good teacher. in a bit.

Comment: final Object[] listItem = new Object[1];

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                listItem[0] = getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
            }
        });//getListView().getOnItemClickListener(


I did this but it returns null

Comment: what returns null? `getItemAtPosition(position)` returns null? why do you want to call `getItemAtPosition`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811536/android-listview-get-item-view-by-position for reference. Got what I need.

Comment: no, no. no, `getChildAt` has nothing to do with the adapter, what do you want to achieve actually when clicking on list view item?

Comment: I don't know how to get the Button element. The link made me get button in linearlayout of xml. After I got Button element, I will put action when specific button is clicked.

Comment: what do you need Button for? instead R.layout.populate_list use for example android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 which has one nicely formatted `TextView`

Comment: What we are trying to tell you is that you can click on literally anything to perform an action. Buttons like in the picture look strange and a simple TextView look cleaner (plus you do not need to find the button in order to set a click listener on it)

Comment: It looks weird because I'm not making the ui front-end at the moment. I'm trying to make the back end work first. Can I know where the user clicked if I used the method that catches when the user clicks on anything?

Comment: `geListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
                                                Log.d("test:", "test");
                                            }
                                        });
`
I tried this but it does not produce. The Log

Comment: did you use a std `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as your layout resource in `SCA` constructor?

Comment: guys. I used android.R.Id.simple_list_item_1 and your recommendations work. answer and I will mark as correct answer

Comment: so now you see how simple it was, wasn't it?

Comment: yeah. haha. thank you for your patience.